# ERROR Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `elevation` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface

I am Creating a Tinder Clone in React Native and working on UI. But having some difficulty in showing images on top of the screen. I used zIndex but it didn't effect because it doesn't work on Android, I used elevation but it is giving me the error plus warning too. Here is the Code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  useWindowDimensions,
  Image,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import Card from './src/components/TinderCard';
import users from './assets/data/users';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useDerivedValue,
  interpolate,
  withSpring,
  runOnJS,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {PanGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import like from './assets/images/LIKE.png';
import nope from './assets/images/nope.png';

const ROTATION = 60;
const SWIPE_VELOCITY = 800;

const App = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [nexttIndex, setNextIndex] = useState(currentIndex + 1);

  const currentProfile = users[currentIndex];
  const nextProfile = users[nexttIndex];

  const {width: screenWidth} = useWindowDimensions();
  const hiddenTranslateX = 2 * screenWidth;
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
  const rotate = useDerivedValue(
    () =>
      interpolate(translateX.value, [0, hiddenTranslateX], [0, ROTATION]) +
      'deg',
  );

  const cardStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: translateX.value,
      },
      {rotate: rotate.value},
    ],
  }));

  const nextCardStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        scale: interpolate(
          translateX.value,
          [-hiddenTranslateX, 0, hiddenTranslateX],
          [1, 0.8, 1],
        ),
      },
    ],
    opacity: interpolate(
      translateX.value,
      [-hiddenTranslateX, 0, hiddenTranslateX],
      [1, 0.5, 1],
    ),
  }));

  const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (_, context) => {
      context.startX = translateX.value;
    },
    onActive: (event, context) => {
      translateX.value = context.startX + event.translationX;
    },
    onEnd: event => {
      if (Math.abs(event.velocityX) < SWIPE_VELOCITY) {
        translateX.value = withSpring(0);
        return;
      }
      translateX.value = withSpring(
        hiddenTranslateX * Math.sign(event.velocityX),
        {},
        () => runOnJS(setCurrentIndex)(currentIndex + 1),
      );
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    translateX.value = 0;
    setNextIndex(currentIndex + 1);
  }, [currentIndex, translateX]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {nextProfile && (
        <View style={styles.nextCardContainer}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.animatedCard, nextCardStyle]}>
            <Card user={nextProfile} />
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      )}
      {currentProfile && (
        <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.animatedCard, cardStyle]}>
            <Image source={like} style={styles.like} resizeMode="contain" />
            <Image source={nope} style={styles.like} resizeMode="contain" />

            <Card user={currentProfile} />
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  animatedCard: {
    width: '90%',
    height: '70%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  nextCardContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },

  like: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Help me to figure out what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an ImageBackground instead? If you're trying to add box-shadow then and [React native image background example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

Comment: No I have a Card and i want those two images on top of that card. Thats why i am using position absolute and top property with zIndex and elevation. But images are not showing up on the card